# Fetching Core Data objects in the background: objects not faulted

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I need some help in using objects from Core Data with GCD; I seem to get NSManagedObjects that are aren't faulted into the main thread, even when I access their properties. Would appreciate some help.

This is what I'm doing: on launch, I need to load a list of Persons from the Core Data DB, do some custom processing in the background, then reload the table to show the names. I am following the guidelines for Core Data multi-threading by only passing in the objectIDs into the GCD queues. But when I reload the tableview on the main thread, I never see the name (or other properties) displayed for the contacts, and on closer inspection, the NSManagedObjects turn out to be faults on the main thread, even though I access various properties in cellForRowAtIndexPath. The name property is visible in the background thread when I NSLog it; and it's also showing correctly on the main thread in NSLogs in cellForRowAtIndexPath. But they don't show in the tableView no matter what I do. I tried accessing the name property using the dot notation, as well as valueForKey, but neither worked.

Here's my code …. it's called from the FRC initializer:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController 
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) 
    {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    __fetchedResultsController = [self newFetchedResultsControllerWithSearch:nil]; // creates a new FRC

    [self filterAllContactsIntoDictionary: __fetchedResultsController];
    return [[__fetchedResultsController retain] autorelease];
}  


- (void) filterAllContactsIntoDictionary: (NSFetchedResultsController *) frc
{

    NSArray *fetchedIDs = [[frc fetchedObjects] valueForKey:@"objectID"];
    NSArray *fetched = [frc fetchedObjects];

    if (filterMainQueue == nil) {
        filterMainQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.queue.FilterMainQueue", NULL);
    }
    dispatch_async(self.filterMainQueue, ^{

        NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease];
        [backgroundContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];
        NSMutableArray *backgroundObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: fetchedIDs.count];

        // load the NSManagedObjects in this background context
        for (NSManagedObjectID *personID in fetchedIDs)
        {
            Person *personInContext = (Person *) [backgroundContext objectWithID: personID];
            [backgroundObjects addObject:personInContext];
        }
        [self internal_filterFetchedContacts: backgroundObjects]; // loads contacts into custom buckets

        // done loading contacts into character buckets ... reload tableview on main thread before moving on
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            CGPoint savedOffset = [self.tableView contentOffset];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self.tableView setContentOffset:savedOffset];

        });
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way to explicitly make the Person objects fire their faults on the main thread? Or am I doing something wrong with GCD queues and Core Data that I'm not aware of? 
Thanks.

Comment: I'd love to help you out. It would be helpful to know exactly what "[self internal_filterFetchedContacts: backgroundObjects]" does.

And, Id like to know where your CellForRowAtIndexPath gets its data from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not take the easy route, since you are not saving anything new ?
Instead of creating an extra context for the background thread and working with IDs, use the main `managedObjectContext` in the background thread after locking it.

for example:

```
- (void) filterAllContactsIntoDictionary: (NSFetchedResultsController *) frc
{

    if (filterMainQueue == nil) {
        filterMainQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.queue.FilterMainQueue", NULL);
    }
    dispatch_async(self.filterMainQueue, ^{

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = ... // get the main context.
        [context lock];     // lock the context.

        // do something with the context as if it were on the main thread.

        [context unlock];   // unlock the context.

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           CGPoint savedOffset = [self.tableView contentOffset];
           [self.tableView reloadData];
           [self.tableView setContentOffset:savedOffset];
       });
   });
}
```

This works for me when I call a method with `performSelectorInBackground`, so I guess it should work for GCD dispatch too.

Comment: Does locking the context stall the main thread (so the UI will be frozen)?

Comment: No it doesn't. The UI works fine while the context is locked.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working fine right now, so I'll mark this as the correct answer. My only concern was passing NSManagedObjects to a different queue for background processing, but if I can use the same context and NSManagedObjects on another queue (after locking the context), it should work. Will test it thoroughly to make sure it's robust, but seems to work right now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` is your friend. You'll need to tell the MOC on the main thread that there have been changes elsewhere. This will do the trick.

[Here's Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html). To quote from there:

> This method refreshes any objects which have been updated in the other context, faults in any newly-inserted objects, and invokes deleteObject:: on those which have been deleted.

Comment: But nothing's saving in the background thread. It's just loading up some transient properties. So there's no NSNotification object to pass into mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: original answer removed, OP is not fetching in the background

I looked closer at your code and it doesn't look like you are doing anything that will change data and/or affect the context on the main thread.

1. You have a `fetchedResultsController` on the main thread. Presumably, this is working and your table is populating with data. Is this true?
2. When `filterAllContentsIntoDictionary` is invoked, you pass an array of the `fetchedResultsController`'s current objectIDs to a background thread and do some processing on them (presumably filtering them based on some criteria) but you are not changing data and saving `backgroundContext`.
3. `internalFilterFetchedContents` is a black box. Without knowing what you intend for it to do, hard to say why it's not working.
4. When this is done, you reload the table on the main thread.

You haven't made any changes to the store, the context, or the fetchedResultsController so of course, the table shows the same data it did before. The missing details to help further are:

1. Is your `tableView` showing correct data from the `fetchedResultsController` to begin with? If not, most likely your only problem is in handling the `tableView` delegate and dataSource methods and the rest of this isn't really relevant.
2. What do you intend to happen in `filterAllContentsIntoDictionary` and `internalFilterFetchedContents`?
3. If your intent is to filter the data as displayed by the `fetchedResultsController` not sure you need to do anything in the background. If you modify the fetchRequest and do `performFetch` again your table will reload based on the new results.

I you need more help, please answer my questions, add more relevant code to your post and let me know if I'm missing anything wrt the problem and what you're trying to accomplish.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but if you look at the code, I'm not fetching in the background ... I'm post-processing the objects that were fetched on the main thread.

Comment: ok, I'll look closer at the code. The title of your question refers to fetching in the background so probably should change that.

Comment: internalFilterFetchedContents just goes through the names and puts them into the correct buckets for showing contacts (A, B, C etc), and does a little bit of customization with the sorting. The tableview works fine if I don't do this post-processing in the background, and do the work on the main thread (but it can take 4-5 seconds to load for long lists). When doing internalFilterFetchedContents in the background, it shows all the rows and sorts them correctly, it's just that they don't have names or any other properties being displayed.

Comment: Let's back up a bit. What is the data source for your table view? Is it the NSFetchedResultsController? Whatever filtering/sorting you are doing, whether in the background or foreground, needs to affect your data source. If your data source is a generated dictionary after a fetch request then @iska's answer may be relevant. However, if that's the case your whole implementation seems suspect to me. You wouldn't need a fetchedResultsController. Why can't you specify all your filtering and sorting in the fetch request used to configure the fetchedResultsController?

Comment: There's some customization that needs to be done with the filtering / sorting, that isn't possible to achieve with the FRC directly. The data source is configured fine (it uses a generated dictionary), since all the rows show up correctly (without properties displayed). Also, if I filter off the main queue, it works fine. So I'll mark iska's answer as correct, since I tried it and it seems to be working. The worry was with passing NSMangedObj's to a different queue / context, but if I can use the same context on another queue (after locking it), it should work for my purpose.